# Zend framework in Xampp

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp

I recently downloaded the full package version(recommended) of ZendFramework(2.0.5).And tried and failed to install in xampp(version 1.7.4) also my php version is 5.3.5 .

I have done almost everything that is said to do like-

1.find php.ini and add path

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library\zend\;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;"
```

2.Extract the downloaded Zend Framework folder and copy to your PHP include path.

I have also checked the folder(xampp,php,Zend) permissions too.I have checked and rechecked my tries multiple times but that error is not solved.

```
Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library\zend\;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;
```

It has already taken mine whole day to check other forums,get ideas but none of then works.Please help .Thanks

Comment: When you downloaded Zend, was it contained in a folder named with a version number?  Mine was.  Does `\xampp\php\Zend\library\zend\ ` actually contain the file `Loader.php`, or is it in some sub folder?

Comment: when i downloaded it was in ZendFramework-2.0.5 and i extracted and change the folder name to Zend and inside there are folders( bin,demos,library,resources,vendor) and files (composer.json,LICENSE and README) and i checked inside Zend\library\zend there is no loader.php file instead there is LoaderPluginManager php file

Comment: Ok.  That is the problem.  Inside the directory that you renamed, there is a directory called `library`.  And inside that, there is a folder called `Zend`.  That is what needs to be on your include path, because that is the folder that contains `Loader.php`.

Comment: I have tried it yesterday also and today after you told me to so (i.e now my path is include_path=".;C:xampp\php\PEAR\;C:xampp\php\Zend" ) but still the same error and again loader.php is not found while i search through the addrress bar.How come a fully packeged version miss loader.php file or am i not getting any clue here about the loader.php file.(Is it loader.php or LoaderPluginmanager.php if so my Zend folder only contains LoaderPluginmanager.php only not exactly loader.php)

Comment: You understand the goal, right?  Search your filesystem for Loader.php if you have to, and put its path into your include.  If your copy of Zend doesn't contain that file, you need to try downloading it again.

Comment: hey there i downloaded different version three of them 1.12.0(having loader.php),1.10.8(having loader.php),2.0.5(not) and tried but still it is not working same errror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your path should probably be `C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend`.
2. You shoulnd't take the framework to the global include path but have it as a dependency in your project, soon you'll have two projects with two different versions of ZF and then the global option creates troubles

Comment: please would you mind checking the path.And does your answer means the Zend folder should be out or php folder or what?

Comment: What happens if you copy this path C:\xampp\php\Zend\library\zend\ into your Windows explorer address bar?

Comment: My answer means that your project should have ZF as a local dependency and you should not add ZF to your php include path therefore.

Comment: the folders inside zend are listed

Answer (score 0):

Hi there finally after doing every possible tries,my error was gone.
I don't know other cases but in my case i have done a series of mistake.So as i corrected them the error was gone.Here is what i did

1.In ZendFramework-2.0.5 the loader.php was missing.So following error occured

```
Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library\zend\;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;
```

For this i downloaded the ZendFramework-1.12.0(only in my case).And Loader.php was there

2.No two mistake of mine was i fractured the path from half.
   i.e.If my folder structure was like
   ZendFramework-1.12.0/library/Zend/..I add the half path to php.ini file

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR\;C:\xampp\php\Zend;"
```

which was a mistake so i, gave the path before the library folder

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR\;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library;"
```

and placed the folders according to path.

3.And what about environmental variables i read about?
They are not neccessary while installing the ZendFramework for the first time.After it i am not in that condn to say whether it should be added or not environmantal variables

```
C:\xampp\php
```

So,after doing above mentioned corrections and checking through the installation checker the error was gone.

And remember to restart(start and stop) the apache server after a tiny change in php.ini file.
thanks to markus-tharkun and Seth Battin a lot.You saved me.