# Where to place Zend and which path to change?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I downloaded and extracted Zend Framework and it is inside a folder named `ZendFramework-2.0.6`.
Documentation says that I need to change `php.ini - include_path` line.
I hope - this is that line (unchanged): `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"`
[On this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858926/zend-framework-in-xampp), accepted answer says that i shouldn't change this path (if I understand well).
Could someone clarify where I should place `ZendFramework-2.0.6` folder, which path and how I need to change it ?
I'm using xampp 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely up to you but it is a common practice to place it into the `vendor` directory.

However, I recommend using composer for installation as it automatically installs dependencies and configures your autoloading. It's surely a good idea to start with the [Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/), the [README.md](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/README.md) explains the installation process with composer.

You don't need to change the `include_path` in this case.

Comment: Daniel, `vendor` directory is `inside` downloaded `ZendFramework-2.0.6` directory !?

Comment: There is one too. I mean <your_application_root>/vendor.

Comment: Excuse me, my application is a site I'm creating, and there is no any `vendor` folder. Also there is no in `xampp`, `htdocs`... Where is that root ?

Comment: You have to create it inside your project / application directory. Also, create a directory named "public" and configure your HTTPd to use it as document root. I strongly recommend you to check the [docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) on this and get started with the Skeleton Application. From there, you've got a good point to start from.