# how to install zend in xmpp in windows 8

Tags: php, windows, git, apache, zend-framework

I know this question is just being asked many times but I have some problem either with ports.

I have xampp installed on windows 8 with port 8081 and then I just create a directory with name **zend** in htdocs and install git.
Now I downloaded git clone **`git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git`** using git bas and copy all files from this folder and move the to zend directory in htdocs.

also update composer with address **C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar self-update** and install it with address **C:\xampp\php\php.exe composer.phar install**

and now I had Open httpd-vhosts.conf file from C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra and add this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/zend/public"
    ServerName zend
    ServerAlias www.zend
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/new/public">
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and last I Opened host file from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and add this code:

127.0.0.1 new

but still **HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found**. error if found

how to make it work?

Comment: I there any need to use port number with it

Comment: Just Replace new with zend and restart apache and try to run it with **zend/** on browser but problem is still same

Comment: earlier it was 80 and the new one is placed below `<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/zend/public"
    ServerName zend
    ServerAlias www.zend
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/zend/public">
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: i just test zend with following [link] http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/zend/testing-your-zend-framework-installation and it fails it show some error message **Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR
**

Comment: Do `composer install` on your project's directory so composer will fetch all the required components in your project from composer.json

Comment: I just found my answer from the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858926/zend-framework-in-xampp

Comment: Thanks you for giving you precious time... :)

Comment: Oh no it's ok.. I have did this using zend documentation that's why i'm helping you to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently downloaded the full package version(recommended) of ZendFramework-1.12.9 
and copy content it to C:/xampp/php/with Zend and then

find php.ini and add path

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR\;C:\xampp\php\Zend\library;"
```